# Set longitude & latitude manually

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, location-services

Is it possible to set longitude & latitude manually for my Android phones.

Comment: Explain your purpose or problem and we can be more helpful.

Comment: Problem is that when I start my location for map at that time my  phone sending longitude latitude in one of another application so I want that I set manually  my phones longitude latitude so is it possible ?

Comment: @Pitty wish you would have explained that previously... Once you set a mock location, that's the location for every app until you manually change it or turn off mock location. Your GPS or other location services will not work meaning regardless of your actual location, the phone and every app will always think they are at the manually defined location.

Comment: Pitty, as you permanently rollback edits that make your question understandable, I've now closed it as "unclear".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is called "Mock Location" in Android and it is designed for developers to test location services in their apps for development purposes. You need to enable it in Developer Options, then use an app from the Play Store to set your location. A quick search for "mock location", "GPS faker", or "Fake location" will yield multiple choices in apps to accomplish this.

You may find this is less useful than you think, in general location based apps such as location based games (Ingress is a good example) will know they are being tricked and either not function or function in a reduced capacity.

Comment: so It is possible to send my fake longitude latitude to the particular application. If any application of my phone want to access my location at that time my manually set location will send. ?

Comment: Yes. But the app will know it's a fake location.